# Best practice to add a layout handle for my custom module?

Tags: layout, best-practice

I think I read somewhere that the best place to add a layout handle for a custom module was through the local.xml file in layouts folder. However, almost all modules that I have seen, never has one used the local.xml. Is it the best practice to use local.xml?

Do you have a link to an article explaining this practice? Also, say I just want to add a lone js/css file to the layout on every page, would local.xml's default handle be the best practice to do it OR what is the best approach for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a layout file in your custom module and then create this file in the layout directory, so in config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        ...
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <yourmodule>
                    <file>layoutfilename.xml</file>
                </yourmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And then create the layout file `layoutfilename.xml` and inside this declare your layout handles and blocks etc just like any layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        ...
        <reference name="head">
            ...
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/somejsfile.js</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Say I am working off of a fresh Magento install which theme's layout directory should I add my layout file to?

Say there is a custom theme installed, in that case which theme should I add my layout file to?

Comment: @ParasSood always use the `base/default` directory for your custom theme files, because this will be used as a fallback anway. Maybe also use `default/default` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Additionally, mind that it is considered best practice to include the namespace and extension name in the layout file name. Hence, use something like `namespace_extension.xml`.

Comment: Not sure I agree it's best practice to include the namespace in the layout filename, but certainly the module name is good to use as the filename like you see with core modules (i.e. catalog.xml, checkout.xml, review.xml and so on).  Also my advice would be if your are planning to make your module available to third parties, i.e. it's not built just for that particular install then using base/default for layout and template files is best, otherwise I would say put them in the theme directory.

Comment: ok, great. Thank you for all the answers Simon and Jonathan.